# Fatal error: Unable to read **** bytes in. It's about FTP hexadecimal Download

Tags: ftp

-PHP be Zend encrypted to run after a year then download FTP to the local environment report "Unable to read 44367 bytes in F:\nginx\APMServ5.2.6" beg solution.

Comment: When using FTP upload binary approach must be adopted. This problem has been solved. Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm you are reading an **encrypted PHP file** that was encoded by ZEND. The encoded time that specified during encryption *should have expired*.

Comment: Exactly the upload mode should be set to **binary** when you are uploading ZEND encoded files. Sorry i forgot to mention it in the first point.

Comment: When using FTP upload binary approach must be adopted.